# Passing variables in Terraform init

Tags: terraform

I am trying to pass variables in terraform init but it does not seem to work.
I have assigned the variables in a terraform.tfvars file.

```
terraform init -backend=${TF_STATE_S3_ENABLE} -force-copy \
-input=false \
-backend-config "bucket=${TF_STATE_S3_BUCKET}" \
-backend-config "key=${APPLICATION}/${ENVIRONMENT}/terraform.tfstate" \
-backend-config "region=${TF_STATE_S3_BUCKET_REGION}"
```

However the below one works

```
terraform init -backend=true -force-copy \
-input=false \
-backend-config "bucket=s3terraform12" \
-backend-config "key=app/dev/terraform.tfstate" \
-backend-config "region=us-east-1"
```

Any help on this please?

Comment: Are you saying that `TF_STATE_S3_ENABLE` is set in a tfvars file? That won't work. At this point it's just shell variables so you'd need to define them in your shell script/session.

Comment: Thankyou..I figured out passing environment variable worked

Answer (score 0):

I passed values by setting as environment variables and that worked..